# Hardened (extended temperature range) router

Tags: wifi, router, switch

I'm looking for a 4 - 6 port (2-3 might work) router that has an extended temperature range to say -40 degrees F/C (-20 F would likely be fine) that is cost effective. Most I have seen is in the $600 to $1500 range, and that is quite expensive for residential use. BONUS for if it has single mode fiber port (or 2) built in (SFP module need to be added is fine). another optional Bonus is Wifi onboard.

I can find un-managed switches that are hardened for a reasonable price ($200 or less)...the router thing is what has me searching.

Thanks in advance for the help.